# Azure DevOps - Can I have work item auto-id numbering separated by project?

Tags: azure-devops

If I create a work-item in project 1 with id 100 then the next work-item would be 101 if I create another work-item but in project 2. I need work-item id 100 in project 1 and work-item id 100 (or whatever) in project 2. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I have work item auto-id numbering separated by project?

For this issue,I think it is impossible to make work items automatically numbered in their respective projects. Currently this is designed like so.

The scope of our work is an organization, sometimes we will need multiple projects to work together, so the id of the work item is applied to the entire organization. If there are workitems with the same id in different projects, then we will be confused when we query work items across projects.

In addition since **work item ID is unique identifier which is assigned by system**, so we can not custom the work item ID when creating a work item. You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/about-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### The unfortunate answer is: no.

The reason lies in the fact that the work item ID is also used as the single unique identifier to link work across projects in the same project collection (on-premise) or organization (cloud). Hence, the number must be unique in the whole collection.

There have been multiple attempts in the past to separate projects and the identifiers. All have met an untimely end due to the complexity involved and backwards compatibility concerns.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing

Comment: If this answer solve your issue ,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.