# Reset Id from task Azure Devops in Boards

Tags: azure-devops, devops, scrum, azure-boards

As the image shows, for each task that is created in my backlog, devops generates an Id for each task. In my implantation studies, the Id grew and now that I'm going to implant it, I would need it to start from 1 and not based on my last one. How do I do a reset?

[image]

Comment: You can create a new organization for your final implementation, which will result in work item ids starting at 1.

Comment: Understand! Thanks for the help, I'm going to do this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would need it to start from 1 and not based on my last one. How do I
>   do a reset?

Sorry but we **can't reset** WIT ID. There's no option in Azure Devops supports the reset of Work Item ID.

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/about-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#track-work-to-be-performed): Each work item is based on a work item type and is assigned ***an identifier which is unique*** within an organization(Service) or project collection(Server).

Azure Devops Service doesn't re-use unique identifier, because that makes nasty problems to troubleshoot. So the ID won't be reset even after we delete all the work Items and Projects in Organization.

Just as **DevOpsy** suggests, you should create one new organization for your final usage. And then the WIT ID will start at 1.

Similar discussions about WIT ID number see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333820/azure-devops-can-i-have-work-item-auto-id-numbering-separated-by-project) and [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/221). Hope it helps to resolve your puzzle and provides correct direction :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, for sure you helped me in this puzzle lol ...
I'm going to start a new project.