# Disable cross-project incremental items numbering within organization

Tags: azure-devops

I've just created several projects in azure devops and seems like it by default increases item numbering on organization level, not on individual projects

Is there a way to disable this and increase numbering inside each project separately?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps - Can I have work item auto-id numbering separated by project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333820/azure-devops-can-i-have-work-item-auto-id-numbering-separated-by-project)

Comment: @EricSmith Perfectly. Thx!